# PyDev import in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, pydev, openrave

I just installed Eclipse Indigo, in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, and installed Pydev with it. I did the following:

(1) set python interpreters by pressing Auto config  in Window > Preferences > PyDev > Editor > Interpreter-Python

(2) set system Pythonpath through Window > Preferences > PyDev > Editor > Interpreter-Python

```
(a) pressed New Folder and added /usr/lib/python2.6
```

I am trying to run an openrave code in eclipse and have all the required openrave libraries installed. "openravepy" is in the directory /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages.

My problems is that it seems that the import is not successful that a few function calls return error type : PyDev Problem. It says 'Undefined Variable: ...'

here are some snippets of the code:

```
from itertools import izip 
from openravepy import * 
from numpy import *

import time

class FastGrasping:
   class GraspingException(Exception):
       def __init__(self,args):
            self.args=args

       def __init__(self,robot,target):
            self.robot = robot
            self.ikmodel = databases.inversekinematics.InverseKinematicsModel(robot=robot,iktype=IkParameterization.Type.Transform6D)
```

--databases is part of openravepy and described as undefined variable.

I've read a few threads and I already did the following

(1) Remove and readd pydev

(2) I've run the code previously, it used to work with eclipse helios and pydev setup. so, I Deleted and reinstall eclipses helios and indigo and repeat the process of adding pydev and pythonpath again and again.

Anyone know hows can I fix this? or is this a bug in pydev?

thanks in advance.

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding 'openravepy' to the forced builtins (see: http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html for details)?

Also, does it run properly? (i.e.: the issue only happens in the PyDev code-analysis or also when you run the code in Python from within PyDev?)

Comment: Adding openravepy to the forced builtins fixes the problem. This should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the Auto config does not always auto select the site-packages directory. This is where most installed modules reside, numpy for example on my machine. Try doing auto-config once more and also select the directory ending in site-packages, if you have not done so already.